# SQL server analysis service user defined hierarchies

Tags: ssas, hierarchy

I am trying to understand how does the attribute-based slicing of data work in SQL server analysis service cubes. So far, I have either the option of NOT creating a user hierarchy and slicing only based on attributed and that works as expected, although no SSAS benefits are actually used, if choosing this.
As soon as I create the hierarchy, I have to use two attributes or more to make a the attribute unique and here comes the problem - in the hierarchy you can see that the members are actually duplicated (in a way).
It makes sense, because a select distinct on:
Country A and City A is different from Country A and City B and Country B and City A. What I want is to see only Country A,B and City A and B and not city **A**,B,**A**. (notice A is a duplicate)
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try SQL Server Analysis Services, SQL Server Analysis Services lets you create user-defined hierarchies. A hierarchy is a collection of levels based on attributes. For example, a time hierarchy might contain the Year, Quarter, Month, Week, and Day levels. In some hierarchies, each member attribute uniquely implies the member attribute above it. This is sometimes referred to as a natural hierarchy. A hierarchy can be used by end users to browse cube data. Define hierarchies by using the Hierarchies pane of Dimension Designer in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).

When you create a user-defined hierarchy, the hierarchy might become ragged. A ragged hierarchy is where the logical parent member of at least one member is not in the level immediately above the member. If you have a ragged hierarchy, there are settings that control whether the missing members are visible and how to display the missing members. For more information, see Ragged Hierarchies.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/user-defined-hierarchies-create?view=sql-server-2014